# Constraint one generic parameter to be a subtype of the other

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a passthrough method that will call Unity to register a type.  This is the body of the method I am trying to create:

```
public static void RegisterType<T,U>()
{
    myContainer.RegisterType<T, U>();
}
```

the myContainer property is an IUnityContainer. When I try to build this, I get

The type 'U' cannot be used as type parameter 'TTo' in the generic type or method 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer, params Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InjectionMember[])'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'U' to 'T'.

How can I tell the compiler that U does implement the interface T?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Will not this work:

```
public static void RegisterType<T,U>() where U : T
{
    myContainer.RegisterType<T, U>();
}
```

?

Comment: Just checked it. It compiles without any errors You was faster to answer :)